# Using unicode arrow characters for variable names or enum cases

Tags: ios, swift, unicode, enums

I wanted to utilize the fact that swift supports unicode characters in the names of variables but I can't get it to work. I have a `UIView` subclass that I draw in certain direction. My plan was to have an enum like this:

```
enum ShapeDirection {
    case ←
    case →
    case ↑
    case ↓
    case ↖
    case ↗
    case ↘
    case ↙
}
```

which I thought would be valid, but I keep getting this error:

> Unary operand cannot be separated from its operand

I tried to give to `ShapeDirection` a type (`String`) and assign values to each case, but the problem is still the same. I also tried to initialize a stand-alone variable with one of the arrows as name, but I get the same error. Does it mean that this particular set of unicode characters is unsupported by the compiler? Is there equivalently complete set of all direction arrows?

---

**EDIT:**

For those wondering about what is clean code, what is readable and how the story ended up - I opted for simple cases North, South, East, West etc. with the arrows as the raw values in `String` format.

Comment: I don't have any Swift experience atm but even this is somehow funny I think this is a terrible idea at the same time. Don't confuse source code readers. Keep it simple when you can. Hope this is just a finger exercise and this doesn't make it into production code.

Comment: Code is not about "being cool", it is about readability and understandability by other developers. On the cool side why not use for error messages. 

Comment: @zaph: awesome idea :D

Comment: Well, I don't see the difference in readability if I have southWest or ↙. Both are perfectly clear. In fact, some people have actually problems with the directions when written instead of shown.

Comment: @Michael: if this is a challenge, this might be already a criterion for exclusion on touching source at all. Keep in mind that you already have problems making this to work. When different encodings come into the game, then I am not sure how this will end.

Comment: How do you enter those characters and will the next developer know how? But no problem clean code is not cool.

Comment: Updated my answer: allowed in operators but not in identifiers.

Comment: Thank you for your input on clean code. I think your opinion is quite clear. Thankfully Jesper read the question and provided me with an answer I was looking for.

Comment: I think the reason they are disallowed is in part a way to still maintain the clean code distinction between operators and identifiers. It's clear what's an operator in `a + b`; it should be clear what's an operator in `a → b`. Regardless, I think letting the individual developer make the decision for themselves is a good idea. Choosing a bad glyph for an operator or enum case is the tip of an iceberg of horrible decisions bad developers may make. Let's not trim the capabilities of good developers. And for an enum case, in Xcode, these all show up in statement completion (Codesense) after `.`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: They are allowed in operators, but [explicitly not in identifiers (the names of things)](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH30-ID412):

> identifier-head → U+2070–U+20CF, U+2100–U+218F, [U+2190 and forward missing] U+2460–U+24FF, or U+2776–U+2793

So this works as intended, or at least as designed.

---

<s>This sounds like a bug. [All of these characters](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%20case%20%E2%86%90%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20%E2%86%92%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20%E2%86%91%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20%E2%86%93%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20%E2%86%96%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20%E2%86%97%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20%E2%86%98%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20%E2%86%99) are available [inside the following range of the Swift grammar](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH30-ID418):</s>

> <s>operator-head → U+2190–U+23FF</s>

<s>...so it sounds like you struck a bug or don't have the file saved in e.g. UTF-8.</s>

Comment: The characters Michal wanted to use. See the question.